# Trim HashSet<string>

Tags: c#, .net, hashset

values and _values are both `HashSet<string>`
I need to trim all the values.

What I need is this

```
values = _values.Trim();
```

But that is not valid syntax

**Edit**

This is what I am doing now but it seems messy

```
values.Clear();
foreach (string s in _values)
{
   values.Add(s.Trim());
}
```

Comment: Unless you can trim values before they're added to `_values`, this is probably the simplest solution.

Comment: What is "better"? Can you explain it?

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria Something cleaner or more efficient.

Comment: `values = new HashSet<string>(_values.Select(x => x.Trim()));` an alternative option.You wont have to clear Hashset

Comment: @Paparazzi This isn't Code Review.  You need to actually have a problem to solve for a question to be on topic.

Comment: @ClearLogic Clear might be faster than new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Better" is arguable, but you could use the built-in method `UnionWith` and some LINQ for a nice one liner to replace your foreach. Think of it as the closest equivalent to an AddRange, except with the restrictions of a set of course.

```
values.Clear();
values.UnionWith(_values.Select(x => x.Trim()));
```

Comment: I wouldn't call this better, only 1 line shorter (ignoring the braces in the question). It's definitely not more efficient than the code in the question.

Comment: I like this better